# Raster to Polygon

Tags: python, python-3.x, pixel, vector-graphics

I did Raster to vector conversion using the below code. But I didn't get the pixel values as a field in my vector file. How can I write the pixel values also? The attribute should look like below attached image.

```
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import gdal

# get raster data source
open_image = gdal.Open("/home/sat/Projects/asu/Crop_Stage/Baliya.tif")
input_band = open_image.GetRasterBand(1)

# create output data source
output_shp = "/home/sat/Projects/asu/Crop_Stage/Baliya/"
shp_driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
# create output file name
output_shapefile = shp_driver.CreateDataSource(output_shp + "\\baliya_rasTOvec.shp" )
new_shapefile = output_shapefile.CreateLayer(output_shp, srs = None )

gdal.Polygonize(input_band, None, new_shapefile, -1, [], callback=None)
new_shapefile.SyncToDisk()
```

[image]